# Excel-VBA Import Module from text file (without requiring trust center)

Tags: excel, vba, module

I'm trying to create a custom library of subs and functions saved as .txt files in a network location where various users of the workbook I'm creating can import them based on which userform function they select. The users of the workbook are only going to be using the workbook through the userforms. I don't want to require them to modify their security trust center settings for this import libraries code to work, so I don't want to use the `wb.VBproject.References.import` command, or make them add-in.

I found this method which works great, but only as long as no other workbooks are open. If another workbook is open, this code ends up inserting a new module in that other workbook instead, and then the userform calls are meaningless.

I don't understand how this is possible, since I'm referencing all of this code within a "With ThisWorkbook" statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub importLib(libName As String)
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Path = "C:\Users\(username)\Desktop\excelLibraries\" 'Example only, my path is actually a network location
  lib = Path & libName
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  With wb
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wbModules As Modules

    Set wbModules = .Application.Modules 'wb=ThisWorkbook, but doesn't point to this workbook when other workbooks open???

    'wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import lib '---> library saved as .bas, but this requires the user to change their security settings
    'wb.VBProject.References.AddFromFile lib '---> library saved as add-in reference, but this requires user to change security settings

'----This method works when no other workbooks are open
    For Each a In wbModules 'Clear any previous Library Module
        If a.Name = "Library" Then
            a.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Set m = wbModules.Add 'Create a new Library Module
    m.Name = "Library"
    m.InsertFile lib 'Insert the code
   On Error GoTo 0
 End With
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub

 Sub callsub()
  importLib "library1.txt"
 End Sub
```

Comment: Note: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and see if there are any errors. This makes you blind because it just hides all error messages but the error still occur. Errors you don't see cannot be fixed.

Comment: I did run this with the error resume next and on error goto 0 statements commented out, but did not receive any errors. The code runs the same, creating the module in the other open workbook.

Answer (score 7):

Making the following changes seemed to work for me.

1. Change `Dim wbModules As Modules` to `Dim wbModules`. Otherwise I get a type-mismatch error.
2. Remove the `.Application` in `Set wbModules = .Application.Modules`.

**EDIT:**

As [@Mathieu Guindon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon) has pointed out in a comment, but worth preserving in the question body, `Application` refers to the `Excel` application instance, the *host*. The `Modules` collection contains all open modules, regardless of the workbook.

Comment: Wow! Bigben, this worked for me as well, but I'm not exactly sure why? Does referencing the .Application refer to all open modules in excel, regardless of workbook? If so, then this would explain why simply setting Set wbModules = .Modules keeps it contained within the workbook.

Comment: @ArturoPino `Application` is the top-level object, i.e. the `Excel` application instance, the *host*.

Comment: @ArturoPino could only find the Access [`Modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.modules) documentation, but yes the `Modules` collection contains all open modules.

Comment: I'm running into some more issues: I've corrected the code as shown above, but it seems that it will randomly not rename the Module in the n.Name = "Library" line, and leaves it as "Module10" or "Module11", etc. 

However, when I debug.print the m.Names for each module that was added, it prints the name I intended, i.e. "Library." Somehow, it's changing the name, but not displaying the new name in the Modules folder. So when I try to delete the module by name, it doesn't find it, but when I try to re-add a new module, it thinks the name already exists... I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what to make of that. If it persists you could always ask a new question to start a new thread on that different issue.

Comment: @BigBen It seems to happen if I import a library from within an imported library... In other words, if I import a library that has code that imports another library. I modified my code to only import libraries from modules that stay in the workbook, and it looks like it works fine. I'm not sure what the reason for that is, but it's very strange. I probably won't spend any more time on it.

Comment: Could this method be used to import userforms as well? Or does that still require the "Trust access to vba object model"?

Comment: @27560 I doubt a similar approach exists for userforms.

Comment: @ArturoPino could you post the updated code? I’m running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the following through the VBA editor

Tools > References > Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3

This will allow the code to remove "Library" then reimport the new code.