# Import source from txt or bas file

Tags: vba, vbe

I want to store source code of VBA macro in .bas or .txt file and run it when user runs macro. I have macro that is used by multiple people, and I would like to store file on server to prevent them to use older versions of same macro. I found following line in stackoverflow and placed it in module code that should import code

```
'Library should be turned on Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim VBPrj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Set VBPrj = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject
    Set VBCom = VBPrj.VBComponents("Module1")
    VBCom.CodeModule.AddFromFile ("C:\Users\lietu\OneDrive\Documents\tests\Module1.txt")
End Sub
```

then I created txt file with following code in right location

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub main()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why dont you just use an Excel Add-In? (XLAM file)

Comment: Because I want to edit text file with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Perhaps explain what isn't working with your code above?

Comment: Please look into this post [Excel-VBA Import Module from text file (without requiring trust center)][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221055/excel-vba-import-module-from-text-file-without-requiring-trust-center], if it meets your reuirement.It works for me for similar situation.

Comment: Personally, I think you are asking for more problems than it is worth, but over time you will probably see that for yourself.

Comment: Edited code in question to make it more clear. Problem is that it works by adding code from txt file in front of code in excel file, but I want that code in txt file is executed.

Comment: It’s still not clear what isn’t working. ITMT, Check these two projects: https://github.com/mattpalermo/VBA-Import-Export and https://github.com/spences10/VBA-IDE-Code-Export

Comment: I'm not trying to import or export code, I'm trying to call VBA code in txt file from excel(.xlsm file) and execute what is inside txt file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to execute code in a text file as a VBA "macro". The programming language/environment/interface simply does not work that way - no ifs, ands or buts - no workarounds.

The content of a text or bas file *must* be imported into a VBA project, using code similar to what's in the question.

In order to be able to use the VB Extensibility libraries that this code depends on, a specific security setting in the host Office application must be disabled, making this kind of approach unreliable, at best. The setting cannot be disabled using code, for understandable reasons.

Indeed, the approach proposed in the question would be a massive security risk...