# Modules is always empty in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, module

I was looking at this question: [Excel-VBA Import Module from text file (without requiring trust center)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221055/excel-vba-import-module-from-text-file-without-requiring-trust-center)

The code presented makes use of the `.Modules` property member which seems to be a collection of VBA modules.

However, I can't seem to use it in Excel VBA. It always returns a collection with zero objects or I get a mismatch error:

```vb
Sub Test1()

 Dim mds As Modules
 Set mds = Application.Modules
 Debug.Print mds.Count
 'Output: 0

End Sub

Sub Test2()

 Dim mds As Modules
 Set mds = ThisWorkbook.Modules 'This line will return a type mismatch error
 Debug.Print mds.Count

End Sub

Sub Test3()

 Dim mds
 Set mds = ThisWorkbook.Modules
 Debug.Print mds.Count
 'Output: 0

End Sub
```

This problem seems to be specific to Excel VBA because if I add a VBA module to an Access project and try to run `Test1`, I get a non-zero number. Also note that [Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.modules) is only documented for Access.

I tried to look at the definition in the Object Browser. It's a bit weird because the property is hidden and it is returning a `Sheets` object instead of `Modules`.

[image]

Was that feature removed from Excel for security reasons or something?
I'm using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16907.20000) 64-bit.

Comment: Please refers to BigBen's reply on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221055/excel-vba-import-module-from-text-file-without-requiring-trust-center. `Application.Modules` can be used with Excel 365 although it is not documented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel-VBA Import Module from text file (without requiring trust center)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221055/excel-vba-import-module-from-text-file-without-requiring-trust-center)

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome I've read the answer from BigBen. The sub `Test3` in my question follows both recommendations from BigBen, but it still doesn't work. I get the output 0.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Modules` only catches modules which are loaded with `<module object>.InsertFile`. The `normal` modules are `NOT` in its coverage.  @DecimalTurn

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome Oh I see! That's what I was missing. Only the ones added via `<Modules>.Add` will be there. It wasn't obvious from the original question IMO that normal modules shouldn't be there as well. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook.Modules` (or `Application.Modules`) is a secret object which is not mentioned on Microsoft Excel online documents. It only includes modules which are created via `<Modules>.Add`. The normal modules are `NOT` in its coverage.

Using `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents` can manipulate all VBA components, but enabling `Trust access to the VBA project object model` is needed.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim mds As Module, lib As String
    Debug.Print "Before:" & ThisWorkbook.Modules.Count
    Set mds = ThisWorkbook.Modules.Add 'Create a new Library Module
    mds.Name = "Library"
    lib = "d:\temp\demo.bas"
    mds.InsertFile lib 'Insert the code
    Debug.Print "After:" & ThisWorkbook.Modules.Count
    Debug.Print "VBCs:" & ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
Before:0
After:1
VBCs:4
```

> **4 VBC**: Sheet1, ThisWorkbook, Library, Module1

[image]